# Finding Set of strings from list of pairs (string, int) with maximum int value

Tags: python, string, set, max

I have a list of `(str,int)` pairs

`list_word = [('AND', 1), ('BECAUSE', 1), ('OF', 1), ('AFRIAD', 1), ('NEVER', 1), ('CATS', 2), ('ARE', 2), ('FRIENDS', 1), ('DOGS', 2)]`

This basically says how many times each word showed up in a text.

What I want to get is the set of words with maximum occurrence along with maximum occurrence number. So, in the above example, I want to get

`(set(['CATS', 'DOGS','ARE']), 2)`

The solution I can think of is looping through the list. But is there any elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Calling your variable `list` can be a dangerous thing to do.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing out. I was just writing here for ease of clarity. Editing now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two linear scans, first to find the maximal element:

```
maxcount = max(map(itemgetter(1), mylist))
```

then a second to pull out the values you care about:

```
maxset = {word for word, count in mylist if count == maxcount}, maxcount
```

If you needed to get the sets for more than just the maximal count, you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to accumulate by count in a single pass:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sets_by_count = defaultdict(set)

for word, count in mylist:
    sets_by_count[count].add(word)
```

Which can then be followed by `allcounts = sorted(sets_by_count.items(), key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)` to get a `list` of `count, set` pairs, from highest to lowest count (with minimal sorting work, since it's sorting only a number of items equal to the unique counts, not all words).

Answer (score 0):

Convert `list` to `dict` with *key* as count and *value* as set of words. Find the `max` value of key, and it;s corresponding value

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_list = [('AND', 1), ('BECAUSE', 1), ('OF', 1), ('AFRIAD', 1), ('NEVER', 1), ('CATS', 2), ('ARE', 2), ('FRIENDS', 1), ('DOGS', 2)]
my_dict = defaultdict(set)
for k, v in my_list:
    my_dict[v].add(k)

max_value = max(my_dict.keys())
print (my_dict[max_value], max_value)
# prints: (set(['CATS', 'ARE', 'DOGS']), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the more pythonic solutions are certainly easier on the eye, unfortunately the requirement for two scans, or building data-structures you don't really want is significantly slower.

The following fairly boring solution is about ~55% faster than the dict solution, and ~70% faster than the comprehension based solutions based on the provided example data (and my implementations, machine, benchmarking etc.)

This almost certainly down to the single scan here rather than two.

```
word_occs = [
    ('AND', 1), ('BECAUSE', 1), ('OF', 1), ('AFRIAD', 1), ('NEVER', 1),
    ('CATS', 2), ('ARE', 2), ('FRIENDS', 1), ('DOGS', 2)
]


def linear_scan(word_occs):
    max_val = 0
    max_set = None

    for word, occ in word_occs:
        if occ == max_val:
            max_set.add(word)

        elif occ > max_val:
            max_val, max_set = occ, {word}

    return max_set, max_val
```

To be fair, they are all blazing fast and in your case readability might be more important.